Modify data in Always Encrypted columns with PowerShell
I have a local SQL Server database with Always Encrypted columns, and a master key stored in Azure Key Vault. I can easily perform CRUD operations with a .NET web application, but I have a requirement to modify (insert/update) data via PowerShell.
I have spent a number of days investigating this but I can't get it working. There are a couple of SO posts from a few years ago (Unable to insert into an always encrypted table using PowerShell and Updating T-SQL always encrypted column with PowerShell), but I haven't been to get updates/inserts working with AKV.
Can anyone help with an example of how to do this in PowerShell please?
Invoke-sqlcmd has a KeyVaultAccessToken switch, so while I can pass an Azure access token and perform SELECT queries, it doesn’t support parameterized queries so inserts/updates are not possible.
# Invoke-Sqlcmd SELECT QUERY WORKS
# Connect to Azure account.
Import-Module Az.Accounts -MinimumVersion 2.2.0
Connect-AzAccount

# Obtain an access token for key vaults. 
$keyVaultAccessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://vault.azure.net).Token

# Pass the token to the cmdlet, so that it can use it to authenticate to Azure when decrypting data protected with Always Encrypted.
$connString = 'Data Source=MYSERVER;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;Column Encryption Setting=Enabled'
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM MyTable' -ConnectionString $connString -KeyVaultAccessToken $keyVaultAccessToken

I've tried invoke-dbaquery from dbatools, this supports parameterized queries, but I can’t figure out how to get this to work with AKV.
# Invoke-DbaQuery HOW TO CONFIGURE AKV PROVIDER/TOKEN?
$server = Connect-DbaInstance -SqlInstance 'myserver' -Database 'mydb' -AlwaysEncrypted -TrustServerCertificate 

$params = @{
a = New-DbaSqlParameter -Direction Input -ParameterName "@a" -DbType AnsiStringFixedLength -Size 4 -SqlValue "test" -ForceColumnEncryption
b = New-DbaSqlParameter -Direction Input -ParameterName "@b" -DbType AnsiStringFixedLength -Size 8 -SqlValue "testval2" -ForceColumnEncryption
c = New-DbaSqlParameter -Direction Input -ParameterName "@c" -DbType AnsiStringFixedLength -Size 8 -SqlValue "testval3" -ForceColumnEncryption
}

Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $server -Query 'insert into [dbo].[table] ([val1],[val2],[val3]) values (@a, @b, @c)' -SqlParameter $params

I've also tried using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient as suggested in the linked posts above, but again I can't figure out how to initialise and register the AKV, and how to pass/use the access token. I get the following error from both Ddbatools and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient when attempting an insert/update query. I understand the error but don't know how to resolve it.

Invalid key store provider name: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. A key store provider name must denote either a system key store provider or a registered custom key store provider. Valid system key store provider names are: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE', 'MSSQL_CNG_STORE', 'MSSQL_CSP_PROVIDER'


Invoke-Sqlcmd only wraps up common use cases, I think you'll need to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient directly. Are you registering Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider anywhere? See: Example demonstrating use of Azure Key Vault provider with Always Encrypted enabled with secure enclaves

Thanks. This is the bit I'm stuck on. I can't quite figure out the syntax in PowerShell to register the provider and associate it with the connection. I've added Add-Type -Path “PathTo\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider.dll" and tried
New-Object Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.AlwaysEncrypted.AzureKeyVaultProvider.SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider(Get-Token) where Get-Token returns my access token but I get New-Object: Cannot find an overload for "SqlColumnEncryptionAzureKeyVaultProvider" and the argument count: "1".. Am I on the track?
